# How to including angular material libraries within the karma test bed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

So I am meeting an issue with Angular 4 unit testing.

"Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'mdMenuTriggerFor' since it isn't a known property of 'button'."

Anyone has idea or documentation reference for including Angular Material within the karma test? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post code of your `TestBed.configureTestingModule` method? I suspect you should import something like `MdMenuModule` there

Comment: Thank you yurzui!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import [`MdMenuModule`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/menu/index.ts) in `TestBed` by adding it to `imports` list of `TestBed`.

```
import { MdMenuModule } from '@angular/material';
...
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ MdMenuModule ],
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Thank you!! That was exactly what my problem was! :D

Comment: @shirley-li if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I see! Thank you again for the tips.